# Lists into Array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I have 3 lists and I need them to be 1 `np.array()` with 3 rows. The append method has not been working because it is created 3 separate arrays.

```
A = array([[1, 4, 1],
       [4, 1, 9],
       [1, 9, 1]])

[0.01665703 0.06662812 0.01665703]
[0.00049017 0.00012254 0.00110289]
[0.00012333 0.00110994 0.00012333]
```

**ideal output (dtype: numpy.ndarray):**

```
[[0.01665703 0.06662812 0.01665703]
 [0.00049017 0.00012254 0.00110289]
[0.00012333 0.00110994 0.00012333]]
```

Attempted Code:

```
em = []
for list in A:
    result = list / np.exp(list).sum(axis=0)   
    em.append(result)
```

Attempted code's output:

```
[array([0.01665703, 0.06662812, 0.01665703]),
 array([0.00049017, 0.00012254, 0.00110289]),
 array([0.00012333, 0.00110994, 0.00012333])]
```

Comment: It's not just `np.array(A)`?

Comment: Can't you try like this [list1, list2, list3], instead of using numpy.

Comment: What is `A`? Why are you calling `np.exp()` and `sum()`? What does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

list_1 = [0.01665703, 0.06662812, 0.01665703]
list_2 = [0.00049017, 0.00012254, 0.00110289]
list_3 = [0.00012333, 0.00110994, 0.00012333]
combined = np.array([
    list_1,
    list_2,
    list_3
])
```

Comment: The OP's code has a list `A`, which seems to be `[list_1, list_2, list_3]`.

Comment: But you used the expected output as your input... The input in the question is `A = array([[1, 4, 1],  [4, 1, 9], [1, 9, 1]])`...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
This gives you the ideal output you specified.
probably not the best way to do it, but it works

```
import numpy as np

myList_1 = [0.01665703, 0.06662812, 0.01665703]
myList_2 = [0.00049017, 0.00012254, 0.00110289]
myList_3 = [0.00012333, 0.00110994, 0.00012333]




print(np.array([myList_1, myList_2, myList_3]))
```

Comment: How does this differ from @K4liber 's answer?

Comment: I answered this before i saw @K4livers answer